# H1 not showing up

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I am having trouble getting my h1 to show up. I see that it is there in inspect element but I do not see it in my browser. I have tried making the text different colors, but with no luck. FYI, I am using EJS so there are those tags but in inspect element I see the right value of the H1. Thank you, Ben

```
<div id="showContainer">
    <div id="showTitle">
        <h1><%=blog.title%></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The html you shared doesn't have H1 in it. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry. I put the wrong code, as I am making a blog with many pages. But I just edited my question with right code.

Comment: When you inspect it in the browser do you see any text inside the `<h1>`? Assuming it isn't empty the most likely cause is a CSS problem. Try removing any CSS files and see whether the `<h1>` shows up.

Comment: Yes I did see text in the H1. I described it in the question!

Comment: I removed the css it worked but with it didn't work. I cannot find the problem. Come up with an answer please.... Thx

Comment: Should <%=blog.title%> be a variable? <%= @blog.title %>

Comment: @Blaksky as you said the problem is with the css, so can you show your css? Without it we can't do anything

Comment: Please share your css to troubleshoot the problem

Comment: We can't debug your application from here... You'll need to create a test case like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/jyj1x18m/  What is 'showContainer' and 'showTitle' ... are you sure there is a `blog.title` etc... there could be hundreds of reasons this is not showing.

Comment: I WOULD BE GETTING A NODE.JS ERROR IF BLOG.TITLE WASN"T SOMETHING KNOW WHAT YOU ARE TAKING ABOUT!

Answer (score -1):

in css add this

```
h1 {
font-size: 24px !important;
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should include `opacity: 1` and `visibility: visible` too, and use `!important` all over the place to make sure it work too

Comment: So my nav bar had position: fixed; and z-index:1; on it. Without it it worked. But I would like by nav bar to have those styles.